# If input field is empty show div

Tags: javascript, html, input, show

I'd like to show the **div** with **id="showDiv"**, but only if the **input** field with **id="textfield"** is empty.

```
<form action="">
 <fieldset>
  <input type="text" id="textfield" value="">
 </fieldset>
</form>

<div id="showDiv" style="width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#6CF;"></div>
```

Anyone know a Javascript that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(document.getElementById("textfield").value == ""){
document.getElementById("showDiv").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p8R7r/) for the example

Comment: Seems as though it doesn't work in Chrome version 54.0.2840.71

Answer (score 4):

You can write:

```
$("#textfield").keyup(function(){
    if($(this).val()) {
        $("#showDiv").hide();
    } else {
        $("#showDiv").show();
    }

});​
```

Live example http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sjS/3/

Comment: I'd rather not use jQuery for this example, but thanks for the fast reply :)

Answer (score 0):

```
If (document.getElementById("textfield").value == "")
 document.GetElementByZid("showDiv").style.display = "inline"
Else
 document.GetElementByZid("showDiv").style.display = "none"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works in Chrome and it's pure JavaScript.

HTML:

```
Enter Text: <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="showColorBox()">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>function showColorBox() {
var x = document.getElementById("myInput");  

var myDiv = document.getElementById("hiddenBox");
if (x.value != "")
{
    myDiv.style.display = "block";
} else {
    myDiv.style.display = "none";
}    
}
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e39vou8s/1/